Does Magento2 write to system.log and exception.log in Production Mode
I have Magento 2.4.6 website and I am in the process of migrating the website to new hosting. On the new hosting on Ubuntu, there are no logs being written on system.log and exception.log while logging is happening on the current Hosting also on Ubuntu. I could not find anywhere on internet or Adobe Experience League how system.log and exception.log are turned on or off. My understanding that we can turn on logging in debug.log in developer mode. But now sure how it is turned on or off for system.log or exception.log. I have given maximum 777 permissions to the files as well as the folder.

Try to run this SSH command :
bin/magento setup:config:set --enable-debug-logging=true

And clear the cache.

Check it in app/etc/env.php file.
'log' => [
    'file' => 'system.log',
    'level' => 'DEBUG',
],
'report' => [
    'file' => 'exception.log',
],


If these settings are missing or incorrect, you can add/update them.
If all settings seem correct and logs still aren't appearing, reviewing web server error logs for clues can provide additional insights into the issue.
